# How do you ignore escapes in character string in a Case_When statement?

Tags: r, string, escaping, case-when

I am trying to organize raw data into specific categories. The data I am trying to organize was entered as free form therefore there are instances where I have to use the whole string and the string contains "\" which R is unable to read as text. The error message is Error: '\s' is an unrecognized escape in character string. How do I ignore the escape within a case_when function?

Comment: Hi @Kzhang, welcome to Stackoverflow! Please include a Minimal, Reproducible Example ( stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ) to help others find a solution to your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to somehow  escape the escape chracter before reading the data. But it would have helped alot if you could give a reproducable exemple of the problem.

Comment: Hi sorry that it was not clear. I figured it out. I was doing a case when statement in a mutate function. The code looked like this
df$'column_name' == "product name/s"
To solve it I just put an extra "/" to escape the escape which resulted in the code
df$'column_name' == "product name//s"